# Issues using img with Bootstrap Grid System

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using a basic Grid System to create a little "Portfolio" where I put images (4 columns and more or less 6 rows), and it looks like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="1st Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="2nd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="3rd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the grid doesn't show up in rows and columns (it gets shown in only a single column, as you can see on the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVxzh.jpg)), what is causing this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I've provided an answer with sample CodePen. Give it a try and see. Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="1st Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    </div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="2nd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    </div class="col-sm">
      <img src="url" alt="3rd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
```

Whats wrong with it:

1. Some opening `<div class="col-sm">` tags are closing tags `</div
   class="col-sm">` a `/` means at the start means a closing tag
2. Missing two closing tags `</div>` for container and row
3. Missing a number at the end of `col-sm` class name this makes the
   columns the size we want **remember each row must add to 12** so if
   you make all `col-sm` to `col-sm-4` you have 3 columns 3 times 4 is
   12 so it works

the `sm` in `col-sm` will make the columns stack on a small screen if you don't want the columns to stack do `col-[enter col size]`

[image: bootstrip-grid] 
This is what the grid looks like visually, you can go to [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) to learn more

Working code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="url" alt="1st Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="url" alt="2nd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="url" alt="3rd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i just re-wrote the cose wrongly here. Should i try with editing the aspect ratio and resolution of the page im coding? (I am using the Basic safari browser on a 2017 macbook air and it wont shows in rows and columns)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Pen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJMLLP)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="url" alt="1st Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="url" alt="2nd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="url" alt="3rd Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="url" alt="4th Event" height="200" width="200"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes: you do have to close your divs, as @rn92 is showing you above. The bootstrap code is fragile in that aspect. You missed both the row closure and the container closure

Comment: As you can see here <https://imgur.com/CIYH6GD> .(i am using 1920x1080 resolution, but it doesn't work even on my normal res) it wont put the images like your code in CodePen even if i literally copy-pasted your code.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you imported all the related JS and CSS libraries?